# Cloudfront path in javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

In my javascript I load in files from Cloudfront.

During development I need to load this in from my local machine.

Is there a way to easily switch the path in javascript dependent on the development environment.

Comment: What environment are you using? You could just locally spoof the dns entry for your CouldFront domain, so that it resolves to 127.0.0.1.

I'd use GasMask to easily manage this on a Mac: http://clockwise.ee/ or just edit your hosts file.

Comment: How are the files loaded ? Ajax calls ? Script tags ? Img tags ? What are the formats of those urls, both remote and local ? Do they share the same filenames and directory structure ?